# 'Object is currently in use elsewhere.' while calling draw string when new bitmap is created in each thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, bitmap, gdi+

I'm trying to make a paint operation where each thread creates a bitmap and a new graphics. That thread draws onto the bitmap until finished then finally draws the bitmap to the control surface which gets locked to avoid the same error. The problem that I'm having is that the `DrawString` method throws that the object is already in use when it's a completely new bitmap and graphics for each thread. Commenting out that second draw operation also avoids the issue. Can only one `DrawString` operation be used at once?

```
Parallel.ForEach(rectangles, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Threads }, rect =>
{
    using Bitmap bitmap = new((int)(tileSize.Width * ChunkSize.Width), (int)(tileSize.Height * ChunkSize.Height));
    using Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    for (int i = rect.X; i < rect.Right; i++)
    {
        for (int j = rect.Y; j < rect.Bottom; j++)
        {
            PointF Location = new PointF(tileSize.Width * (i - rect.Width), tileSize.Height * (j - rect.Height));
            lock (bitmap) // This lock does nothing
            {
                graphics.FillRectangle(renderTiles[i, j].BackBrush, new Rectangle(Location.ToPoint().Add(new Point(5, -1)), tileSize.ToSize().Add(new Size(1, 1))));
                // graphics.DrawString causes error
                graphics.DrawString(renderTiles[i, j].Ico.ToString(), Font, renderTiles[i, j].ForeBrush, Location.ToPoint());
            }
        }
    }
    lock (pe.Graphics)
    {
        pe.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, rect.Location.Multiply(tileSize.ToPoint()));
    }
});
```

Comment: If the `Font` and the `Brush` are not standard ones then you could run into problems. You should cache them by thread.

Comment: @Charlieface Font is `System.Drawing.Font`, brushes are `System.Drawing.HatchBrush`, `System.Drawing.SolidBrush`, `System.Drawing.LinearGradientBrush`. Getting the brush before it throws it seems to always be a `SolidBrush`.

Comment: But are you creating these or are you using one of the standard ones from `Brushes` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.brushes?source=recommendations&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: @Charlieface I see now, I was making my own not sure of the best way to cache them

Comment: Store them in `ThreadLocal` maybe?